# service start: HOSTNAME: command not found

Tags: centos, daemon, hostname

Whenever i try to start a daemon service with the

```
service name start
```

I get the following error:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network: line 3: HOSTNAME: command not found
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

I get the same error message for vsftpd when using the same command.

Using the hostname command i can see my hostname and it is correct.

I am on centOS release 6.6

Not really sure what the problem is, and wondering if anyone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the content of `/etc/sysconfig/network`?

Comment: Could be space characters in a line like `HOSTNAME = some-server`, which should be `HOSTNAME=some-server`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Red Hat-based systems, most services which use networking (including MySQL) load the networking configuration into shell variables by sourcing `/etc/sysconfig/network`. This configuration file contains shell variable assignments similar to:

```
NETWORKING="yes"
NETWORKING_IPV6="no"
HOSTNAME="www.example.com"
GATEWAYDEV="eth0"
```

Your error message indicates that there’s a problem with line 3 of `/etc/sysconfig/network`. Since the shell thinks `HOSTNAME` is a command, I suspect that you have a space after the word `HOSTNAME`, probably something similar to

```
HOSTNAME = "www.example.com"
```

When the first word in a shell command is followed by a space, it is parsed by the shell as being the name of a command. This space should be removed.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job, It's obvious to me now that i should have just edited the network file by the error message. No idea how it happened though.